# Windows Service - C#

Tags: c#, windows, service

How can I run a Windows-Service hourly?

Comment: could you add some more background to your request? what does it do? why do you need a service and not, for example, the task scheduler?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need the service to execute a method hourly, the method basically gets data from a database, and inserts data into a database.

Comment: Most databases have build in support for this kind of administrative tasks

Comment: if you're just dealing with databases, why not create a SQL Task Scheduler instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or just write a simple app and use the systems Task Scheduler Service to run your app every hour - no need to write a service at all this way.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the description of your problem (which only superficial) I can't think in anything else other than the use of the normal service template provided by VS to create a service and use a Timer to trigger the method that you are interested in running every hour.

About Timer you can also check it out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

For some more info about how to create the service, in can have a look in the [msnd web site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

As a simple rule of thumb, never forget to disable the timer just before you starting processing your staff and enable it again at the end

Comment: MSDN contains an example of a simple Alarm class. You can use it to periodically trigger your method. Just make sure to set the new alarm time each time the alarm event is triggered. You can use this approach in your Windows Service. Here's the MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z%28v=VS.90%29.aspx#Y2400 ... You could rewrite this sample to use a Timer instead.

Answer (score 0):

well you can create a service which works at a time interval of 60 minutes

```
        timer1 = new Timer();
        this.timer1.Interval = 1000 * 60* 60;
        this.timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
```

write this code in the onstart method of the windows service and you will be able to run the service in hourly manner.